# Find query with condition depending on parent model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, associations

For the purpose of this question, this is the association tree (all `->` means `hasMany`), all database structure code adheres to CakePHP conventions.

```
Forum -> Section (forum_id) -> Topic (section_id) -> Reply (topic_id)
```

I'd like to run a `$this->Reply->find` query with certain conditions, and I would like the returned `$data["Reply"]` array to only return replies where they belong to `forum_id=X`.

For example, I run a `$this->Reply->find` with certain conditions (these don't matter), and it returns two results with different parents, and when you go up and up until you reach `Forum.id` (or `Section.forum_id`), they differ in `forum_id`.

What I want is to filter the results so they belong to a certain `forum_id`. Since `forum_id` is not a field in the `Reply` model itself, but instead in `Section` (which is two "layers" up), I can't use a `conditions` entry to filter the result.

What should I do?

Comment: You're going to need joins. Look into the `joins` key for the options param on find call.

Comment: Maybe you can use Containable and query from top-down?

Comment: @Dave If I run a `$this->Section->find` with `Containable`, it can only go down to the point of a `Topic`. You can't reach the `Reply` model's data because Topic hasMany Reply, it'd have to process all Topics.

Comment: Why could you only go down to Topic?  Containable can keep going down as long as there are associations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
<?php
$this->Reply->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        Reply::joinLeft('Topic'),
        Topic::joinLeft('Section'),
        Section::joinLeft('Forum'),
    ),
    'conditions' => array('Forum.id' => $forumId),
));
```

https://github.com/tigrang/EasyJoin - This will determine the relationship between the models and create the join arrays for you.

If you don't want to use the plugin, you'll have to specify the joins array manually or rebind the models to be able to use Containable as it would currently create multiple queries rather than joins.